# ORA-01839 error raises while dealing with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I get an error

> ```
> ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified error while comparing to sysdate
> ```

from the following select statement :

```
SELECT NVL(prs.birth_day, '01') AS birth_day,
       NVL(prs.birth_month, '01') AS birth_month,
       NVL(prs.birth_year, '2900') AS birth_year,
       pro.kayitno 
  FROM person prs
  JOIN profil pro
    ON prs.kayitno = pro.kayitno
   and status = 12
 WHERE TO_DATE(NVL(birth_day, '01') || '.' || NVL(birth_month, '01') || '.' ||
              (NVL(prs.birth_year, '2190') + 65),'dd.mm.yyyy') < sysdate;
```

as I'm adding **65** years to birthyear field's value.

Can anybody explain the reason please ?

Comment: can you pleaase add some tables and data, so that we can understand your problem better

Comment: "I add 65 years to birthyear field it gives error" - see if it errors if you *don't* add 65; if it doesn't then it's likely the data you have is valid but includes a leap day (i.e. February 29th in some year). If that is the problem then you could convert to a date and than use `add_months()` to add (65*12) months, which will handle it for you - by adjusting that date to the 28th.

Comment: You are storing day, month and year separately in order to make them nullable (e.g. you know a person's birthdate, but not the year). But in your query you are treating day, month and year as strings. E.g. with `NVL(BIRTH_DAY,'01')` you seem to expect to get the day as a two-digit string from the table. And here: `NVL(person.birth_year, '2190') + 65)` you seem to want to add the number 65 to the string '2190'. Please make sure you are using the appropriate data type both in your table and in your queries. Are you storing the numbers as strings? Please show the table definition.

Comment: Use `WHERE TO_DATE( NVL(birth_day, '01') || '.' || NVL(birth_month, '01') || '.' || NVL(person.birth_year, '2190') DEFAULT null ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'dd.mm.yyyy') IS NULL OR (birth_day = '28' AND birth_month = '02')` in order to find all rows leading to invalid dates.

Answer (score 4):

**NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` (such as `SYSDATE`). `TO_DATE` takes a string as the first argument so you are asking Oracle to implicitly convert the `DATE` value to a string and then explicitly converting it back to a `DATE`. At best, it is pointless and does nothing and, at worst, it either raises an error (as you are seeing) or gives an unexpected output.

If you want to set the time component of a `DATE` to midnight then use `TRUNC` and not `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT NVL(KISI.DOGUMGUN,'01') DOGUMGUN,
       NVL(KISI.DOGUMAY,'01') DOGUMAY,
       NVL(KISI.DOGUMYIL,'2900') DOGUMYIL,
       PROFIL.KAYITNO  KAYITNO     
FROM   ORTKISI KISI           
       INNER JOIN ISTPROFIL PROFIL 
       ON KISI.KAYITNO = PROFIL.KAYITNO
          and PRMISARAMASTATUKAYITNO=12  
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         NVL(DOGUMGUN,'01')||'.'
         ||NVL(DOGUMAY,'01')||'.'
         ||(NVL(KISI.DOGUMYIL,'2190')+65),
         'dd.mm.yyyy'
       ) < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Additionally, anyone born on 29th February on a leap year (i.e. an even numbered year) then when you add 65 years to that date then 29th February will never be a valid date as 65 years on will an odd numbered year and a non-leap year so there would only be 28 days in February in the year when they are 65.

Therefore, even if your dates are all valid then you want to use `ADD_MONTHS` to add 65*12 months and not directly adding years.

```sql
SELECT NVL(KISI.DOGUMGUN,'01') DOGUMGUN,
       NVL(KISI.DOGUMAY,'01') DOGUMAY,
       NVL(KISI.DOGUMYIL,'2900') DOGUMYIL,
       PROFIL.KAYITNO  KAYITNO     
FROM   ORTKISI KISI           
       INNER JOIN ISTPROFIL PROFIL 
       ON KISI.KAYITNO = PROFIL.KAYITNO
          and PRMISARAMASTATUKAYITNO=12  
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(
         TO_DATE(
           NVL(DOGUMGUN,'01')||'.'
           ||NVL(DOGUMAY,'01')||'.'
           ||NVL(KISI.DOGUMYIL,'2190'),
           'dd.mm.yyyy'
         ),
         65 * 12
       ) < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

If that does not fix it then it is likely that the problem is not with your query (although you should still never use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE`) but is with your data and you need to check if you have: a 29th February for a non-leap year, or 31st September, or a 32nd of any month, etc. We cannot check that as you have not supplied any sample data.

If you are on Oracle 12 or later, then you can use `TO_DATE(... DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR, ...)` to catch conversion errors:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(KISI.DOGUMGUN,'01') AS DOGUMGUN,
       COALESCE(KISI.DOGUMAY,'01') AS DOGUMAY,
       COALESCE(KISI.DOGUMYIL,'2900') AS DOGUMYIL,
       PROFIL.KAYITNO AS KAYITNO     
FROM   ORTKISI KISI           
       INNER JOIN ISTPROFIL PROFIL 
       ON KISI.KAYITNO = PROFIL.KAYITNO
          and PRMISARAMASTATUKAYITNO = 12  
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(
         TO_DATE(
           DOGUMGUN||'.'||DOGUMAY||'.'||KISI.DOGUMYIL
           DEFAULT '01-01-2900' ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'dd.mm.yyyy'
         ),
         65 * 12
       ) < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ORTKISI (dogumgun, dogumay, dogumyil, kayitno) AS
SELECT '29', '02', '1940', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '32', '13', '1900', 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ISTPROFIL (kayitno, PRMISARAMASTATUKAYITNO) AS
SELECT 1, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 12 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DOGUMGUN | DOGUMAY | DOGUMYIL | KAYITNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 02 | 1940 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OxU11n3V)

Comment: with trunc it still gives same error

Comment: @HalukÖztürk Updated - you probably have invalid data in your tables.

Comment: Likely, they would get error ORA-01858, not ORA-01839 if the sysdate part is the problem. To me it seems the part before is the issue. Hard to say without sample data. That's why the question has been closed ;)

Comment: @JonasMetzler You can get `ORA-01839` errors if you are on the "correct" date [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0dJBJHzy) And the advice still stands, **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` as it may lead to unexpected or erroneous results.

Comment: It gave "[Error] Execution (16: 2): ORA-43918: This argument must be a literal" error. DB has huge data approximately 1M

Comment: @HalukÖztürk Updated to use string literal in the `DEFAULT` (rather than a date literal) and included a fiddle that shows it working following that change. If it does not work for you then you need to provide a [MRE] which shows what is different from your data and/or setup and my example.